# Add Tag for Open Graph in Salesforce Community

Tags: metadata, lightning-community

I have a dynamic page in a community and I'm adding the  tags to share on social networks:

[image]

When I use the Facebook debugger, it doesn't show me the image, title and description of the page because it seems that the tags are loaded later.
[image]

If I add the labels in the global part of the community. Facebook if it finds the tags and loads the information correctly.

[image]

But the latter does not help me, since image, title and description have to be dynamic.

Does anyone know what is going on?

According to Salesforce, what I'm trying to do is correct: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/advanced-seo-lightning-communities.html

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags on the head markup is loaded dynamically - therefore the Open Graph is not seen by the linter/scaper.

However, for Bing, Google  and spider crawlers, a static version of the site is provided for SEO - therefore the page specific meta descriptions are visible.

There is an open case here to hopefully address this major issue:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352967&type=1